# how to implement Treemap with comparator?

Tags: java, comparator, treemap

The error that i was facing in this Question has been solved and is written below in answer section.

The problem was that the below definition of TreeMap is throwing a compiler error and I wanted to know the reason.

```
Comparator<Student> comparator=new Comparator<Student>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(o1.roll<=o2.roll)
                    return -1;
                else return 1;
            }
        };
        TreeMap<Integer, Student> map=new TreeMap<>(comparator);
```

I dont understand the reason this implementation of Treemap is wrong. Can anyone please explain me about what is going on in here?

Comment: What makes you think the code is wrong? If you are experiencing any unexpected results, please specify clearly what you had expected and how observed result differs, so we may understand your problem/question and may in the end help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** A comparator for a `TreeMap<Integer, Student>` needs to compare `Integer`s, not `Student`s.

A `TreeMap<Integer, Student>` maps from integers (“the keys”) to student objects (“the values”) and keeps the mappings sorted by the integers. Therefore the constructor does not accept a `Comparator<Student>` as argument.

According to the documentation of `TreeMap<K,V>`, the constructor taking a comparator as argument is declared as

```
    TreeMap​(Comparator<? super K> comparator)
```

This means that the comparator must work on type `K`, the type of the keys, or some supertype of `K`. In your case, `K` is `Integer`.

Since the `Integer` class already defines an ordering, the so-called natural ordering, I suggest you don’t need a comparator at all:

```
    TreeMap<Integer, Student> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

If you wanted to store the students by their `roll` number, just insert them like this:

```
        Student me = new Student();
        map.put(me.roll, me);
```

The side effect will be that the map is sorted by `roll`.

PS The information in [the answer by John Kugelman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52128711/5772882) is correct too, a comparator needs to handle three cases. And `Comparator.comparingInt(s -> s.roll)` or `Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getRoll)` (if the class has such a getter) is recommended, not only for the terseness, even more because it’s less error-prone.

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I just needed to reverse the arguments of TreeMap.

Answer (score 6):

`compare()` needs to handle *three* cases: less than, greater than, and equal. You need to return `0` when they're equal.

```
if (o1.roll == o2.roll) {
    return 0;
}
else if (o1.roll < o2.roll) {
    return -1;
}
else {
    return 1;
}
```

[`Integer.compare(int x, int y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-) can do all of this for you:

```
public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
    return Integer.compare(o1.roll, o2.roll);
}
```

In Java 8 you can create the entire comparator in a single line:

```
Map<Integer, Student> map = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(s -> s.roll));
```

Comment: Trying your last line I get `roll cannot be resolved or is not a field`. This is because the compiler looks for `roll` in the `Integer` class, not in `Student`.

Comment: Make sense... I was confused with -1, 0 and 1 uses.